# Can't produce results percentage out of my class

Tags: apex, class

I have this class, but the results for perLost and PerWon is always 0, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
 public List<Opportunity> Stages {get; private set;}
     public Integer counterLost {get;private set;}
     public Integer counterWon {get;private set;}
     public Integer counterRTS {get;private set;}
     public Integer Sum {get;private set;}
     public Double perLost {get;private set;}
     public Double perWon {get;private set;}
> public ClosedLostStages() {   Stages = [ Select Id , StageName , Amount
> , Name , Owner.Name
>              FROM Opportunity
>              WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Lost'];
> 
>  counterLost = [ Select count() 
>                     FROM Opportunity
>                   WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Lost' ];
> 
>  counterWon = [ Select count() 
>                     FROM Opportunity
>                   WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Won' ];
> 
>   Sum = counterWon + counterLost ;    perLost = ((counterLost / Sum) *
> 100) ;    System.debug(perLost + 'Lost percentage');  perWon = 
> ((counterWon / Sum) * 100) ;  System.debug(perWon + 'Won percentage');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that counterLost, counterWon, perLost, Sum, and perWon are all Integer values. Integer division where the numerator is larger than the denominator will always result in a zero mid-calculation (e.g. counterWon/Sum, 25/100 is 0.25, cast as an Integer is 0, resulting in calculating 0 * 100, which is still 0).

To avoid this loss of precision, declare Sum as a Decimal instead of an Integer. This will force counterWon and counterLost to be promoted to a decimal during calculation, and the precision won't be lost. Alternatively, you could also cast Sum to a Decimal, but I like to make the code as legible as possible.

You'll need to get the Integer value back from the calculation if perWon and perLost are integer values. Like so:

```
Sum = counterWon + counterLost;
Integer perLost = ((counterLost / Sum) * 100).intValue();
System.debug(perLost + 'Lost percentage');  
perWon = ((counterWon / Sum) * 100).intValue();
System.debug(perWon + 'Won percentage');
```

---

Now with fully functional example that was written in my developer org:

```
public class ClosedLostStages {
    public List<Opportunity> Stages {get; private set;}
    public Integer counterLost {get;private set;}
    public Integer counterWon {get;private set;}
    public Integer counterRTS {get;private set;}
    public Decimal Sum {get;private set;}
    public Double perLost {get;private set;}
    public Double perWon {get;private set;} 

    public ClosedLostStages() {
        Stages = [Select Id, StageName, Amount, Name, Owner.Name
                  FROM Opportunity
                  WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Lost'];
        counterLost = [ Select count() 
                       FROM Opportunity
                       WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Lost' ];

        counterWon = [ Select count() 
                      FROM Opportunity
                      WHERE   StageName = 'Closed Won' ];

        Sum = counterWon + counterLost ;
        perLost = ((counterLost / Sum) * 100) ;
        System.debug(perLost + 'Lost percentage');
        perWon = ((counterWon / Sum) * 100) ;  
        System.debug(perWon + 'Won percentage');
    }   
}
```

Comment: this is the first part

Comment: public List<Opportunity> Stages {get; private set;}
  public Integer counterLost {get;private set;}
  public Integer counterWon {get;private set;}
  public Integer counterRTS {get;private set;}
  public Integer Sum {get;private set;}
  public Double perLost {get;private set;}
  public Double perWon {get;private set;}

Comment: that gives me error

Comment: @bez What error?

Comment: (ClosedLostStages) Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Integer].intValue()

Comment: @bez See the fully functional example I mocked up. Pay careful attention to data types.

Comment: I just saw it, thank you very much, Sum needed to be decimal

Comment: what does .intValue() suppose to do?

Comment: @bez intValue is a [Decimal](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm), Double](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm) and [Long](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_long.htm) function that converts the type to an integer by truncating everything that won't fit (e.g. decimal places, values outside (+/-)2^31).

Comment: it's give the error [Integer].intValue()